# Java variable initialization different ways of handling?

Tags: java

I just found that Java handles variable initialization in different ways.

Case-1:

```
class A {
    boolean x;
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.x);
    } 
}
```

When I ran above program it shows like "false" as output. But now I am posting other piece of code:

Case-2:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         boolean x;
         System.out.println(x);
    }
 }
```

Now, above piece of code shows that

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
    The local variable x may not have been initialized
```

Why the same thing is handled in very different ways?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: when initializing the class A, it sets it default value(when no value is explicitly initialized) to class A variables. For Case-1, you get x as false as initialized. For the second case, Class A initialized but here x is not class variable, instead local one in main method. Thus you get this error-I guess

Comment: I think it's more conceptual question rather than programming question. And it depends on how they developed Java.

Comment: right, this is sort of conceptual. These things are related here-- how a class  is instantiated first,  how uninitialized variables will be treated

Comment: I post this question becuase I can't find much about this anywhere on net.... If you think it's relevent please upvote so some senior member can see and answer this question.

Comment: First off, I think this is a good question.  Secondly, there is no NullPointerException happening since you are using a primitive boolean.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKrause for letting me know to change my question.

Comment: A local variable must always explicitly been given a value. A field will be defaulted automatically (`null` for objects, special values for primitives like `0` or `false`). That behavior is documented very clearly in the Java Language Specification ([JLS§4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Oracle documentation on [Java Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a
>   default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot
>   initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to
>   assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an
>   uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

So this is an interesting nuance.  If a primitive type variable is locally declared, you must specify a value for it.

Comment: The quoted section also applies to objects (not just primitives).

Answer (score 2):

There are three distinct types of variables:

- static variables - within class;
- member variables - within object
- local variables - having scope limited to a function or block of code

Assumming the variables are not final.
The first two default to 0 or false (when var is a primitive) or 
null (when var is an object) when accessed for read. The last one must be set to a value prior to reading, otherwise the code will not compile.

All of variable types (local, member, static) must be assigned a particular value if defined as final. Such  Initialisation of static final variable can be an inline assignment to a value or it can be done in static initialisation block. Initialisation of final member variables can be done inline, within Initialisation block or within object's constructor (most common - best practice). 
Final local variables initialized inline. There is also "effectively final" variable that is inferred by compiler when it sees that variable will not be changed. Final variables allow compiler to treat and optimize handling of data.

Thats just a couple of basic items to start with. Hope it is helpful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is about why local variables are treated different from non-final member variables: in the example above I do not see any use do declare `boolean x;` instead of `boolean x = false;`, but the last one makes the intent of the programmer clear. Also you are allowed to declare `boolean x;` if you initialize `x` later. Here the compiler error you get is helpful so you don't forget to initialize it in some rare edge case. The compiler couldn't check that if it would be initialized by default.

It's also common to have code like

```
int i;
if (a > b)
    i = 8; // loong code
else
  i = 42; // loong code
```

Initializing `i` would be useless here.

Static and non-static members (non final) are different because the compiler always nulls all fields before running initializers and constructors. Not initializing them to 0 manually is a slight performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Your two examples use different kinds of variables:

1. a **field** (also called instance variable, or member)
2. a **local** variable

You can only use a variable if it has a value / refers to an instance. For **fields**, if you do not explicitly assign a value, they are **defaulted**. That is **not the case** for **local** variables, thus the error.

The default value is `null` for objects and special values for primitives, like `0`, `0.0`, `false` and similar.

---

### Java Language Specification

The JLS clearly defines this behavior and explains how it works. Take a look at chapter [4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) where it states (relevant excerpts):

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>
> - Each class variable, **instance variable**, or array component is initialized with a **default value** when it is created ([§15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), [§15.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2)):
>
>   - For type `boolean`, the default value is `false`.
> - A **local variable** ([§14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4), [§14.14](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14)) must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either **initialization** ([§14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)) or **assignment** ([§15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment ([§16 (*Definite Assignment*)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-16.html)).